# Javascript explode and loop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have created this script to explode numbers from one data-get via php:

```
var n_polls=<?php echo $t_random_number;?>;
var myArray=n_polls.split(','); //explode

for (i=0;i<4;i++)
{
$("#t_sl_poll_"+myArray[i).hide();
}
```

The idea is to give some numbers from php for a random poll system, and I want explode this for close all in loop by the id. The problem is, I see something fail into the explode function for javascript, all time giving me nothing.  How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: You should look at the console for the syntax errors. That `[i)` isn't pretty sight.

Comment: My dude if this it´s writte right $("#t_sl_poll_"+myArray[i).hide();

Comment: if $t_random_number is an array then you should echo json_encode($t_random_number);

Comment: in var n_polls only show number in this format 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: @user2536883 then you should surround the echo "[".$t_random_number."]"

Comment: $("#t_sl_poll_"+myArray[i).hide(); this line contains the syntax error correct it

Comment: Is there any way you can improve the English in this question? I don't mean to be rude, but I'm having a lot of trouble understanding what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at your source. Your error console would tell you the same thing. You're not putting your array (not a number) in quotes, so it fails to compile during runtime:

```
var n_polls="<?php echo $t_random_number;?>";
//QUOTES!   ^                              ^

var myArray=n_polls.split(','); //explode

for (i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    $("#t_sl_poll_"+myArray[i]).hide(); //Missing bracket
    //                       ^
}
```

Now it'd compile to

```
var n_polls="1, 2, 3, 4";
```

instead of

```
var n_polls=1, 2, 3, 4; //Useless non-working code - not enclosed in anything
```

Comment: actually this is wrong... it isn't an array as I originally thought it is a string so it should be surrounded by quotes or json_encoded

Comment: most iportantly, don't explode the array!

Comment: @Orangepill I know - annoyingly enough I had it written out as a string, then saw your comment and was like "damn - he's right!" and changed it. I've changed it back now. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Why explode in Javascript when you could have PHP just insert an array?

```
<?php

$numbers = array(1,2,3,4);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

var n_polls = <?php echo json_encode($numbers); ?>;

for (i in n_polls) {
   $("#t_sl_poll_" + n_polls[i]).hide();
}
```

There's further optimizations that could be done, but this'd be one place to start.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong here.

First: since you apparently hand over a string and not a number from php to javascript you have to write: `var n_polls="<?php echo $t_random_number;?>";`

Second: as pointed out in the comments already, you have to write `$("#t_sl_poll_"+myArray[i]).hide();` to acutally address and element of your array.

Answer (score 0):

your code should work as

```
var myArray= [<?php echo $t_random_number;?>];

for (i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    $("#t_sl_poll_"+myArray[i]).hide();
}
```

Comment: Don't use `new Array(content)`!

Comment: @JanDvorak Thanks for keeping me straight